# Book about future where they use honey instead of money?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, dystopia

I remember reading this about 3 years ago. The main character is a teenage girl who has to learn how to survive in this new world. I think she’s trying to find her brother with the help of some people she met hiding underground in sewers.

It was a newer book when I read it and it’s written in English.

Comment: When did you read it? What language? Any details about the setting/characters? Was it in the future, or alternate present or past? You may want to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory as this is very vague at the moment.

Comment: Was the honey all wrapped up in a five pound note?

Comment: Why is the world new? Is it post-apocalyptic? (Wars, Epidemic, Economic/Social collapse?) Is it more like Blade Runner? (Dregs of society living in the street?)  Is it a new world cause they are not even On Earth?

Answer (score 3):

Ended up finding it at a library. It’s called Stung by Bethany Wiggins.

[image]

> STUNG by Bethany Wiggins starts off with Fiona Tarsis waking up not
>   knowing how she got in her bed. She finds a mark on her hand not
>   knowing what it is but knowing she must hide it. She also notices that
>   her body has matured. And as she looks around her house, everything is
>   destroyed and dull, as if no one had lived there for ages. She doesn't
>   see her mom, dad or siblings and can't remember where they went and
>   why they would leave her. She looks around, and the neighborhood is
>   abandoned.
>
> Fiona meets a girl name Arrin who takes her underground through the
>   tunnels and takes care of her. Arrin also gives her advice on how to
>   survive; she cuts Fiona's hair, and tells her never reveal that she is
>   female.

So it is post apocalyptic, she gets help from people she meets underground, and they teach her to survive, so she can look for her brother.

I cant find any reference to Honey as Money, but the societal collapse was caused by the collapse of the Honey Bees population (Plants cant be pollinated) and The fix by the government made it worse. So due to the scarcity of Bees it makes sense Honey is very valuable and could be the new form of currency.

Its a YA book and does sound interesting. and is followed by a sequel called "Cured"

Comment: Hi welcome! Could you please expand your answer with a summary of the book in order to help other people that may have a similar question.

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons once you merge your accounts via the instructions at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20528/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-account